# Rootless Podman UID mapping and volume mount issues

Tags: apache-kafka, uid, podman, rootless

I am trying to start kafka inside a container via podman-compose.  I am using `/opt/kafka/kafka_2.12-2.4.1/bin/kafka-server-start.sh` which is fine.  However, I am mounting a directory that contains the properties file `/home/vagrant/repos/kafkazookeeper/config:/home/kafka/config`. Right now, this properties file has owner/group permissions of `nobody/nobody`. On the host, the kafka user is `kafka:x:1001:1001::/home/kafka:/bin/bash` but in the container, the kafka user is `kafka:x:1000:0::/opt/kafka/:/bin/bash`

I've tried using `--uidmap 1001:kafka` in the docker-compose.yaml but that didn't work. Any thoughts are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I would highly recommend reading this article: https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/rootless-podman-makes-sense

Users and their UIDs in a container get mapped onto a different set of users and UIDs on the host.  This is controlled by `/etc/subuid` and `/etc/subgid` and you can see the actual mappings when you run `podman unshare cat /proc/self/uid_map`.

If you run the container under the `kafka` user on the host, the `kafka` user is going to be mapped to `root` inside the container. You cannot map the `kafka` user inside the container to the `kafka` user outside the container because `root` is already mapped to it and you can't map two different UIDs in the container to a single one on the host.

I think you can either set the permissions on the config files to be readable by everybody.  Or you can create another user on the host, map it to the `kafka` user inside the container using `--uidmap` and then use the newly created user to control the configuration.